# Linux AWS EC2 Permissions with rsync

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running a default t2.nano ec2 linux ami. Nothing is changed on it. I am trying to rsync my local changes to the server. There is a permissions issue that I don't know enough about to fix.

My structure is as follows. I'm trying to push my work to the technology directory. The technology directory is mapped to a staging domain. i.e. technology.staging.com

`:/var/www/html/technology`

this is from the root, and it does work fine, it's the rsync that is failing.

when I push locally to that directory I get a "failed: Permission denied (13)" error.

I'm running an nginx server and assigned permissions to the www directory as follows:

`sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www`

My user is ec2-user which is the normal default. Here is where I am tripped up. You can see the `var` directory is given root access.

[image]

You can see that the `www` directory then has permissions set to `nginx` so our server can access the files. I believe I need to add the `ec2-user` to this directory as well as the `nginx` user so that I can rsync my files there and the server will still have access I'm just unsure of how to do that.

As a test, I created a `test` directory at this location and it worked successfully.

`:/home/ec2-user/test`

you can see the permission here are set for the `ec2-user` which is why it works i'm sure.

[image]

Here's the command I'm running on my local machine to rsync my files which fails.

`rsync -azP -e "ssh -i /Users/username/devwork/company/comp.pem" company_technology/ ec2-user@1.2.3.4:/var/www/html/technology`

Here's the command that was working.

`rsync -azP -e "ssh -i /Users/username/devwork/company/comp.pem" company_technology/ ec2-user@1.2.3.4:/home/ec2-user/test`

I have done enough research and testing to know that it's a permissions error, I just can't figure out the right way to solve it. Do I need to create a group and assign both the `nginx` and `ec2-user` to the group and then give that group the same permissions level on the `:/var` directory.

Side note, what permissions level do I set for the chown to make these permissions that are currently set?

[image]

I have server config files in the `:/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory that map to the directories I create inside of `:/var/www/html` directory so I can have multiple sites hosted on the server.

So in this example, I have a config file at `:/etc/nginx/conf.d/technology.conf` which maps to the directory at `:/var/www/html/technology`

Thank you in advance, again, I do feel like I have put forth the research and effort to show that I've gone as far as I know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer made sense after I spent roughly a day playing around. You have to give access to both the `ec2-user` and the `nginx` group. I believe you never want to put a user in a group that involves the server itself, I think things would go south.

After changing the owner to both the `ec2-user` and `nginx` group, it still didn't work exactly the way I wanted it to. The reason was, I needed the `nginx` permissions to be updated to what they had when they were assigned the user role.

Basically, the`ec2-user` had write permissions and the server did not. we wanted the user to have write permissions so they could rsync my local files to the directory on the server, and the `nginx` group needed the same level of permissions to display the pages. Now that I think about it, the `nginx` group may have only needed read permissions to display things, but this at least solved the problem for now.

Here is the command I ran on the server to update the ownership and the permissions, as well as the output.

**modify ownership**

`sudo chown -R ec2-user:nginx :/var/www/html/technology`

**modify permissions**

`sudo chmod -R o=rwx,g+rwx,o-w technology`

The end result looks like this

[image]

You can see the permissions match, and the ownership is as we expected. The only thing I have to figure out is after I `rsync` new files to the server, I need to run the previous code to update the permissions again. I'm sure that will come to me later, but I hope this helps anyone in the same situation.

Comment: `rsync` preserves file permissions; why don't you just replicate the numeric `UID/GID` on the development machine?  If that's not an option stand up an `inotifywait ` on the taget directory tree, and run the `chmod/chown` on `write-close` events.